# How to display data from a list view to a activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a list view and a database I want to display the data from the database in another activity so I made a OnItemClickListener for my list view. 
Now I get the position of the ClickListener but because I have made my adapter to display data so the latest input from the user is on top. I nead to reverse the position of the onClick.

At the moment I get:
1
2
3
4

but I need:
4
3
2
1

because of the database id.

If for example the user clicks position 3 on the list I want the database to return the row 3.

ListView:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), JornalListViewClick.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName",position);

        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
});
```

The getRows of the database:

```
public Cursor getAllRowre(){
    String where=null;
    Cursor cursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEY, where, null, null, null,ID_KEY + " DESC", null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

The activity where I want to display the data:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
intValue++;
text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserInputFromListClicked);
Cursor cursor=dbJ.getRowUserInput(intValue+"");

if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        String mes=cursor.getString(0);
        text.setText(mes);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: why dont you just use `ORDER BY` query?

Comment: pass `data.size()+1-position` instead of `position` and data is your items.

Comment: Where should i implement order by

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way:

Use a POJO to store every row retrieved

Implement Comparator and use Collections.sort(List, Comparator) to sort it before putting it into adapter

```
    public class MyData{
        private String field;
        // getter and setter
    }
```

After retrieve the String from database, you can instantiate MyData class and set the string (or more fields) into the instance. Put all results in a Collection. E.g.:

```
    Vector<MyData> listOfResults=new Vector<MyData>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String mes=cursor.getString(0);
            MyData instance=new MyData();
            listOfResults.add(instance);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }   

    return listOfResults;
```

After retrieving data from database, you want to sort it, right? Try this:

```
    Collections.sort(listOfResults,new Comparator<MyData>(){
        public int compareTo(MyData a,MyData b){
            return a.getField().compareTo(b.getField());
        }
    });
```

Inside the Activity containing the ListView, create a private class implementing ListAdapter. E.g.:

```
    private class MyListAdapter implements ListAdapter{
        private Vector<MyData> data;

        public MyListAdapter(Vector<MyData> list){
            data=list;
        }

        /*** other methods you need to implement ***/
    }
```

Instantiate MyListAdapter by supplying the Vector you got from database access method.

Then call setAdapter(ListAdapter) of the ListView inside the Activity after the data is ready.